# Phonegap - Update file from remote url

Tags: cordova

I would like to update images placed in the www directory, for example:

```
assets/www/img1.png
assets/www/img2.png
```

Basically I have a bunch of image in there already and I would like to pull the images from my server and overwrite the existing ones. I was reading the phonegap guides [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html), but unfortunately I could not figure it out myself. Could someone help me with this?

```
var imgNames = ["www.foo.com/img1.png","www.foo.com/img2.png"];
for(var i=0; i < imgNames .length; i++){
    toDlPath = imgNames[i].substring(imgNames[i].lastIndexOf("/") +1); //e.g. img1.png
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(imgNames[i], dlPath, function(e){
        console.log("Successful download of "+e.fullPath);
    }, function(e){
           console.log("error while saving img:");
           console.log(e);
    });
}
```

I tried with FileTransfer but I received this error (tested on Android):

```
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017): {"target":"img1.png","source":"http:\/\/foo.com\/img1.png","code":1}
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017): java.io.FileNotFoundException
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.getFileFromPath(FileTransfer.java:556)
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:444)
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:88)
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:186)
09-28 14:32:14.437: E/FileTransfer(11017):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Phonegap version 1.8.1

Your help is appreciated indeed.

Comment: Is this in IOS or Android ? In IOS any files you download will go to a folder outside of the www/ folder so that might not help you.

Comment: This should be working on both Android ans IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually I did not save the image file directly to the phone rather I converted the image into Base64 String and saved that into the database then I loaded the picture from there.

Thank you [Base64Coder](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java).